# Angular Material Table: custom sort folder and file items

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have different types of items in my `mat-table`: Files and Folders. 
They have to get sorted like in Microsofts file-explorer. Folders can`t be separated from folders and likewise with files. 
All other sorting rules staying the same.
Has anyone an idea how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: .net has a entire library for files and folders but NPM does too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to overwrite the sortData on your MatTableDataSource attached to the table. This is the function that is responsible for sorting records, e.g.

```
this.dataSource.sortData = (data: YourObjectType[], sort: MatSort) => {
 return data.sort((a: YourObjectType, b: YourObjectType => {
   //Sorting logic here
 });
}
```

You can look at the default implementation in the material code on github:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/c2a20c4a035ef57bf598fd78bc7284c180b34c78/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts#L168

Comment: Curious, how would I use this function to sort on an ODATA expanded property? For instance, $orderby=Location/Marina