# Angular mat-table case-insensitive sort is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I have an Angular mat-table that won't sort case-insensitively.  I've tried many different ways and nothing works.  Here's my latest attempt:

**template:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="customer" matSortDirection="asc">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="customer">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Customer Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.customer}}</a> </td>
  </ng-container>...
```

**component**

```
export class Customer {
  customerid: number;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
}

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, sortHeaderId) => data[sortHeaderId].toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
    
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

The dataSource gets populated from a database query.  The table sorts fine but all the uppercase customers appear first, followed by the lower case ones.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried custom sort? check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480695/angular-material-table-custom-sort-foler-and-file-items

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get that method to work either

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is:

```
    export class Customer {
      customerid: number;
      name: string;
      phone: string;
    
      get lowerName(){
        return this.name?.toLowerCase()
      }
   }
```

And in template

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="lowerName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Customer Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.customer}}</a> </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

matColumnDef must fit the property in your view model

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
```